Machine-readable source of baryon and meson properties, including valence quark content
I'm looking for a source of machine-readable data about the experimental values of certain properties of known baryons and mesons, e.g. their isospin, angular momentum, parity, and valence quark content.
The Particle Data Group has a database and API which gets me most of the way there, but it doesn't contain information about their quark content. I would like to avoid having to scrape e.g. the wikipedia entry, or entering the values by hand. Does someone know of a file somewhere with the necessary information? It seems that it MUST exist somewhere, but my google-fu has failed me.

Machine readable....how? And for what purpose? This might help because there exists quite a few formats for this, usually because programs already come with information in this format.

those are only the main quark contents...

Sounds like a great opportunity for you to make such a database for everyone else!

@JonCuster haha I suppose it does. I did mail the PDG group responsible for developing the Python API, and they said, to quote: "Quark content is planned for an upcoming release".

@naturallyInconsistent yes, I specified I was interested in the valence quark content.

@Triatticus well anything I can load into memory with a Python program would be fine. I am interested in applying machine learning techniques to the data.

Have you tried looking up programs that already include physics models like Pythias and Sherpa? These usually contain liars of particle PDG codes and their properties. I haven't used either very much so I don't know how much info each particle is given.

@Triatticus thanks for the suggestion, I'll look those up
